Are there practical use cases for negated SPARQL property paths?
I use sparql property paths regularly, but I recently realized
that I never seem to have a use for the negation operator, which matches a path if it does not involve the specified property or property set.
?source !ex:property ?target

Unlike the case with negated character ranges ([^abcd]) for text search, I can't seem to think of any use cases that would need this. The example in the SPARQL Recommendation is no help:

Negated Property Paths: Find nodes connected but not by rdf:type (either way round):
 { ?x !(rdf:type|^rdf:type) ?y }


Research: I found this SO answer where it's used to work around the lack of variables in sparql path by matching for (x or !x). But this only uses negation for lack of anything more appropriate.
So are there realistic use cases that I am overlooking, where one needs to look for all-but a certain property or property set in a path? Or is the negation operator hardly ever used in practice?

I agree this is syntactic sugar for an operation that is not so common. Sometimes I use it in Wikidata to check whether entities that should be used only for internal purposes are indeed utilised correctly. For example, wd:Q28091153 should only be specified as object for pq:P2241. Thus, for checking possible bad usages one can search for ?x !pq:P2241 wd:Q28091153. I'm following for other examples!

Thank you! Yeah, schema validation makes sense, you should add it as an answer.

@ValerioCocchi, why not just use ?p for this?

Great question. Unfortunately the SPARQL spec doesn’t support variable properties for property paths, so the only way to achieve it is as above.I’ll repost the comment below to make it clearer that you can use * and + as well.

Another useful trick is using it to find out if there is a path between two nodes, e.g. SELECT * WHERE {:startNode (!:doesNotExist)+ ?middleNode . ?middleNode (!:doesNotExist)* :endNode}

@Valerio "Unfortunately the SPARQL spec doesn’t support variable properties for property paths, " --> right... your previous comment used a single hop, now that part makes sense. But your new example uses negation only as a way to get around the lack of variables in paths, exactly as in the SO answer I mentioned in the question. So unfortunately it doesn't help with understanding what this feature was really meant for.

By the way @Valerio, what graph store do you use this on? Does it have usable performance on non-trivial graphs? It looks like a query optimizer's nightmare. :-)

Fair enough @alexis. I'm using RDFox (FD: my employer).

Makes sense, @Valerio! RDFox is very fast, but I imagine this can give it a run for its money :-) Anyway it still seems to me that an unrestricted variable-length wildcard would have been more broadly useful than path negation. (Something amounting to ?_ +, i.e. you could query "connected" but can't bind to the solutions for implementation efficiency reasons.) Strange.

Nice trick Valerio! @alexis Even if the ?p* syntax was allowed, it would not have the same semantics of Valerio's example: using */+ quantifiers on a variable that is going to be bound to some predicate would mean to repeat 0/1 or more times the same predicate. For example, (!:doesNotExist)+ matches :p1/:p2, but a path like ?p* would not, because ?p should either be bound to :p1 or to :p2.

@logi-kal you are right, a different syntax would be needed. I just wanted to put something down, none of this exists anyway :-) (I was trying to make an analogy to bnodes in the sense of "every instance is different", but neeever mind...)

But still my question remains: If the only real use of the negated path syntax is for "nice tricks" (no argument there!), then why was it added in the first place?

One possible use case in which this syntax could be used is some form of schema validation. As for me, sometimes I use it in Wikidata to check whether entities that should be used only for internal purposes are indeed utilised correctly. For example, wd:Q28091153 should only be specified as object for pq:P2241. Thus, for identifying possible bad usages one can search for ?x !pq:P2241 wd:Q28091153.

Future readers might note that even these kind of usages can be tricky if inference schemes are available. For instance, if you're in an OWL ontology and you have a reasoner in place, then for any two individuals, you have x owl:topObjectProperty y, for any individual you have x rdf:type owl:Thing, and so on. (That's not a point against the example you gave, but just a note for the general case.)

@JoshuaTaylor Thank you for having pointed it out. I think in those cases one can use something like ?x !(owl:topObjectProperty|pq:P2241) wd:Q28091153, right?

@JoshuaTaylor you raise a very good point, because in general the open-world assumption means that you can't stipulate the non-existence of additional predicates. For any two resources, there is an unlimited number of potential relations between them (even with meaning "not connected to"). So there might be problems with the formal definition of the negation operator.
